# Cannot use index when creating pandas dataframe from a tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a tuple into a pandas dataframe but I get:

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

The size of the tuple will be different each time, so I may have a tuple with one item, or more than one.If I use the below code it works.

```
import pandas as pd
pl = ({'id': '23329061', 'network_id': '1677614649047'})
df = pd.DataFrame(pl,index=[0])
print(df)
```

however I cannot use index[0] if there is more than one item in the tuple.

```
pl = ({'id': '22056461', 'network_id': '1620222117689'}, {'id': '22516091', 'network_id': '1620222117689'},{'id': '22516091', 'network_id': '1620222117689'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, `pl` is a plain dictionary, **not a tuple**!

One workaround:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(([pl] if isinstance(pl, dict) else pl))
```

Else, just omit the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pl)
```

output:

```
         id     network_id
0  22056461  1620222117689
1  22516091  1620222117689
2  22516091  1620222117689
```

Note that if you really need to pass an index, you can build it programmatically:

```
# index 0, 1, 2
df = pd.DataFrame(pl, index=range(len(pl)))

# index 0, 0, 0
df = pd.DataFrame(pl, index=[0] * len(pl))
```

Comment: I cannot omit the index if the tuple is

`
{'id': '23329061', 'network_id': '1677614649047'}
`

`
pl = ({'id': '23329061', 'network_id': '1677614649047'})
df = pd.DataFrame(pl)
`

Comment: @Pregz you don't have a tuple here `(x)` is `x`, a tuple is defined by a **comma** not by parentheses (`x,` and `(x,)` are tuples)

Comment: `pl = ({'id': '23329061', 'network_id': '1677614649047'},) ; df = pd.DataFrame(pl)` works fine

Comment: I updated my answer with a workaround